# How to convert file from gml to edgelist in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, networkx

Is there any example in python, how to convert file from *.gml to *.edgelist?
Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
In [1]:  import networkx as nx

In [2]:  g = nx.read_gml('gmlFile.gml')

In [3]:  nx.write_edgelist(g, 'edgelistFile.csv', delimiter=',')
```

**Documentation**

[read_gml(path, encoding='UTF-8', relabel=False)](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/generated/networkx.readwrite.gml.read_gml.html?highlight=read_gml)

[write_edgelist(G, path, comments='#', delimiter=' ', data=True, encoding='utf-8')[source]](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/generated/networkx.readwrite.edgelist.write_edgelist.html?highlight=write_edgelist)