# Convert edgelists to GML

Tags: python, gml

Is there a simple way to create a GML file out of edgelists (comma separated) using Python? This is the opposite situation of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24229165/how-to-convert-file-from-gml-to-edgelist-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

I've found a question similar to mine and a solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22768224/unable-to-load-a-simple-csv-in-networkx-in-python?rq=1). I just adapted the solution for my dataset. Hope this is helpful for others.

```
G = nx.read_edgelist('edgelistFile.csv', delimiter=',', nodetype=str, encoding="utf-8")
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have an edge list file (.edges) and want to convert it a gml file, do this. The gml file will get created in your present working directory.

```
import networkx as nx
G= nx.read_edgelist('414.edges') # load edgelist file
nx.write_gml(G, "414.gml") # create gml file
```